# Time of death from Newton’s law of cooling – do I need the initial temperature?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, everyday-life, cooling

> Suppose that a corpse was discovered in a room and its temperature was 32°C at 12pm. The temperature of the room is kept constant at 20°C. Three hours later the temperature of the corpse dropped to 27°C. Find the time of death.

Is it possible to solve this problem question without assuming initial body temperature as 37°C?

Edit: This is why i thought it could be solved.

Here I've taken rate of change of temperature is directly proportional to difference in temperature (and as cooling causes a temperature change I have taken the average temperature minus the room temperature)
Theeta is the initial temperature of corpse 
And "t" is the number of hours since the body died i.e. the time for the body to drop to 32°C.
So is it possible to solve this for "t"?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You do need to assume the temperature at the time of death was 37ºC.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I don’t think that this is your typical homework question, as the question is not about solving the actual task but much more specific, i.e., whether a certain assumption has to be made. In particular you can answer this question without solving the actual problem.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I think you're partially right - this asks something other than how to solve the assigned problem, indeed (or in other words it asks a specific conceptual question), but it does _also_ ask how to solve the assigned problem, and I'd say that part is off topic and should probably be removed if the question is not to be put on hold.

Comment: @DavidZ: Fortunately, the how-to-solve part is irrelevant, as it applies only to the case that the problem can be solved without assuming an initial temperature (which is not the case). Thus, there is no harm in removing it.

Comment: Why do you think you might not need to know the initial temperature?

Comment: Cuz I thought this could be solved assuming it's correct. https://goo.gl/photos/3qsrnSC4hRnBj53a8

Comment: Solved assuming what is correct? It is not clear what you have done in that link. You should post your calculation in the question and explain your reasoning.

Comment: Your calculation of the average temperature difference is not correct. Your use of Newton's Cooling Law is also incorrect. You have 3 unknowns here (including the constant of proportionality) so you cannot find $\theta$ even if the equations were correct.

Comment: Why is the use of Newton's Cooling Law incorrect? Isnt rate of change of temperature proportional to temperature difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the initial body temperature had been 42°C.
Then it would take the corpse some time – let’s say two hours – to cool down to 37°C.
After this, the (thermodynamic) situation is indistinguishable from a fresh corpse at 37°C.
Therefore, both, the fresh corpse and the corpse that started at 42°C need the same time to cool down from 37°C to 32°C.
Consequentially, a corpse with an initial temperature of 37°C takes two hours less to cool down to 32°C than a corpse with an initial temperature of 42°C.

To take an even more blatant example: Suppose the initial temperature had been 20°C. Then it would be impossible that the corpse heated up to 32°C.

So, as the solution to your problem obviously depends on the initial temperature, you need to make assumptions on the initial temperature to solve your problem.